# Replace text with regular expresion

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have this text on a txt file.

```
2019-08-09T15:00:00Z
2019-08-09T15:05:00Z
2019-08-09T15:06:00Z
2019-08-09T15:09:00Z
2019-08-09T15:10:00Z
```

But I want to delete some part of the text, only de date. I need a code o a example on powershell or cmd.

```
15:00:00Z
15:05:00Z
15:06:00Z
15:09:00Z
15:10:00Z
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific issues/errors are you getting? This is something that .Split() could do fairly easily

Comment: This, but it doesn't work because the dates change next day. ```Get-Content -path C:\Data\data.csv -Raw) -replace '2019-08-09T',''```

Comment: @AndrésDíaz so you `Split("T")`

Comment: Yeah, I just need the hours.

Comment: '2019-08-09T15:00:00Z' | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '.*T','' }

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
$firstPart,$secondPart = $string.split('T')
$firstPart
$secondPart
```

Comment: Without the ```$firstpart``` and if possible for cmd or powershell

Comment: This _is_ powershell

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want just the `HH:mm:ss` format there are a lot of ways:

```
$DateTimes = @"
2019-08-09T15:00:00Z
2019-08-09T15:05:00Z
2019-08-09T15:06:00Z
2019-08-09T15:09:00Z
2019-08-09T15:10:00Z
"@ -split '\r?\n'

$DateTimes | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Method1 = (Get-Date $_ -f 'T')
        Method2 = "{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f (Get-Date $_)
        Method3 = ($_ -split 'T|Z')[1]
        Method4 = $_.split('TZ')[1]
    }
}
```

---

```
Method1  Method2  Method3  Method4
-------  -------  -------  -------
17:00:00 17:00:00 15:00:00 15:00:00
17:05:00 17:05:00 15:05:00 15:05:00
17:06:00 17:06:00 15:06:00 15:06:00
17:09:00 17:09:00 15:09:00 15:09:00
17:10:00 17:10:00 15:10:00 15:10:00
```

You may have noticed that my localtime is 2 hours ahead of Z(ulu) time, what Get-Date takes into account.